# Not able display the result correctly

Tags: javascript

I have problem in my code. I should display name of the programmers and the languages in an array that they know and at the end I should print the count of how many of them know the language JAVA. My count method prints the numbers separately but not the total one. Can you please explain the reason?

```js
class Developer{
    constructor(a,b,c,d){
        this.name = a
        this.surname = b;
        this.age = c;
        this.experience = d;
        this.languages = [];
    }
    wrtie(){
        this.languages.forEach(el=>{
            let p = document.createElement("p")
            let d = document.createElement("div")
            let lang = document.createElement("p")
            p.innerHTML = `${this.name} ${this.surname}`
            lang.innerHTML = "Languages: " +el
            document.body.append(d)
            d.append(p,lang)
            
        })
    }
    push(x){
        this.languages.push(x)
    }
    totalcount(){
        let h2 = document.createElement("h2")
        let count = 0
        for (let i of this.languages){
          if(i.includes("JAVA")){
            count++;
            h2.innerHTML = count
            document.body.append(h2)
            console.log(i)
        } 
        }
    }
}

class FrontEndDeveloper extends Developer{
    constructor(a,b,c,d){
        super(a,b,c,d)
    }
}
class BackEndDeveloper extends Developer{
    constructor(a,b,c,d){
        super(a,b,c,d)
    }
    
}
class FullStackDeveloper extends Developer{
    constructor(a,b,c,d){
        super(a,b,c,d)
    }
    
}
let front = new FrontEndDeveloper("Armen" , "Mkrtchyan" , 5, 10)
front.push(["HTML/CSS", "JS","Node.JS"])
front.wrtie()
front.totalcount()

let back = new BackEndDeveloper("Armine" , "Gabrielyan" , 6, 7)
back.push(["Node.JS" , "Angular", "PHP","JAVA"])
back.wrtie()
back.totalcount()

let full = new FullStackDeveloper("Anahit" , "Aramyan" , 8, 5)
full.push(["HTML/CSS" , "JS", "PHP","JAVA"])
full.wrtie()
full.totalcount()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: push() and write() function is JS Reserved function for array and other, you have overwritten it. Name your functions other than this.

Comment: It did not help.

Comment: Error in console ? Catch error and print that.

Comment: I don't have errors. The main problem is: it displays numbers separately. I have two arrays that include language JAVA and when I call totalsum method it prints 1/1 but not 2

Comment: Okay so it is taking that as string, convert them to numbers, use parseInt () function of JS then add them. Try this one, see is it working 

Comment: It is not connected with string. It just counts separately

Comment: Make it undependent from the developer. Why is this method in your developer class?

Comment: Alex how can I make it undependent from the mother class?

Comment: @AramayisYeghiazaryan do the function outside of your class definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define this method in your class.

Counting how many of your developers have the skill JAVA has nothing to search in your developer class.

### Solution

- Write a function(outside of your developer class) which takes as argument an array of developers.
- Loop through the developers and check for every developer if his languages contain the language JAVA.
- If yes increment your counter.
- Then display the counter as amount of developers which have the skill JAVA.

**The Function**

```
   totalcount(front, back, full);
   
   function totalcount(...developers){{
            let h2 = document.createElement("h2")
            let count = 0
            for (let i of developers){
           
              if(i.languages[0].includes("JAVA")){
                count++;
               
                document.body.append(h2)
            } 
              h2.innerHTML = count;
              document.body.append(h2);
            }
        }
```

**The Full Snippet**

```js
    class Developer{
        constructor(a,b,c,d){
            this.name = a
            this.surname = b;
            this.age = c;
            this.experience = d;
            this.languages = [];
        }
        wrtie(){
            this.languages.forEach(el=>{
                let p = document.createElement("p")
                let d = document.createElement("div")
                let lang = document.createElement("p")
                p.innerHTML = `${this.name} ${this.surname}`
                lang.innerHTML = "Languages: " +el
                document.body.append(d)
                d.append(p,lang)
                
            })
        }
        push(x){
            this.languages.push(x)
        }
       
    }

    class FrontEndDeveloper extends Developer{
        constructor(a,b,c,d){
            super(a,b,c,d)
        }
    }
    class BackEndDeveloper extends Developer{
        constructor(a,b,c,d){
            super(a,b,c,d)
        }
        
    }
    class FullStackDeveloper extends Developer{
        constructor(a,b,c,d){
            super(a,b,c,d)
        }
        
    }
    let front = new FrontEndDeveloper("Armen" , "Mkrtchyan" , 5, 10)
    front.push(["HTML/CSS", "JS","Node.JS"])
    front.wrtie()
    

    let back = new BackEndDeveloper("Armine" , "Gabrielyan" , 6, 7)
    back.push(["Node.JS" , "Angular", "PHP","JAVA"])
    back.wrtie()
   

    let full = new FullStackDeveloper("Anahit" , "Aramyan" , 8, 5)
    full.push(["HTML/CSS" , "JS", "PHP","JAVA"])
    full.wrtie()
    

    
    totalcount(front, back, full);
   
   function totalcount(...developers){
            let h2 = document.createElement("h2")
            let count = 0
            for (let i of developers){
           
              if(i.languages[0].includes("JAVA")){
                count++;
               
                document.body.append(h2)
            } 
              h2.innerHTML = count;
              document.body.append(h2);
            }
        }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome :) if you think this is helpful you can accept this answer.

Comment: Why do I need the developers array?

Comment: I have updated my answer to this beautiful JS syntax function(...) 
Now you can call it directly with your developers

Comment: oh. I think that I am far from understanding. (:

Comment: I just cannot understand why I cannot have the method inside the mother class, if the three classes extend from the Developer class?

Comment: But why you should have it there? It has nothing to do with a developer. When you think in Object Orientated Programming then a developer has some skills a name and a age for example.
When you now want to count how many of the developers have a specific skill then this is not a functionality of your developer. 
For sure you can also do a function inside your class which takes as argument other developers and then count how many of them has a specific skill but it would not make any sense at all.